# Colors on PS4 remotes

Tags: ps4, controllers

Kind of a dumb question but I've been wondering about this for a while, what determines the color of the bar on PS4 remotes, what do they mean? Just curious.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the game, the colors and their meanings can vary greatly.

By default, this is what they mean:

- Orange: charging
- White: turned on, not yet assigned to a player
- Blue: assigned to Player 1
- Red: assigned to Player 2
- Green: assigned to Player 3 <sup>*</sup>
- Purple: assigned to Player 4 <sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup>: According to this image I found on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BGA9X9W):

[image: DS4 colors]

Since I only own 2 DS4, I can only confirm that the colors for Players 1 and 2 are accurate. With [the PS4 supporting only up to 4 controllers](https://www.destructoid.com/console-war-over-ps4-only-supports-four-controllers-261247.phtml), all player colors are accounted for.

Comment: Some games also change the color of the bar.

Comment: @stelar7. I believe I covered that with my first sentence, which literally starts with "Depending on the game".

Comment: It’s interesting how they bucked the trend of using yellow for the fourth player. It probably looked too similar to the charging colour.

Comment: @JanHasebos I'd imagine it's to match the DualShock face button colors.

Comment: @JanHasebos while charging the color isn't static, see [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-my-PS4-controller-charging): "The PS4 controller will slowly flash a steady color (most often yellow or orange) of about 1–1.5 pulses every second while charging".

Comment: The only thing you forgot to mention is that if the light bar is a dark-ish gray, that means the controller is off ;)